# Difference between Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC and Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

What's the difference between Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC and Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC?

[Kendo-ui](http://www.kendoui.com/faq/mvc-faq.aspx)

I had read there post but couldn't understand the exact difference.
According to them

> Modularity: With Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC you can leverage
>   the client and server pieces independently, or together, depending on
>   your preferences or project requirements. This cannot be done with
>   Telerik Extensions.

What is the exact meaning of these point? Can anybody explain these with an example?

There are only 2 differences?

Which one is best to use between these two components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the docs :

1-**Device reach with HTML5 and JavaScript:** Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC gives you the ability to target both desktop and mobile devices using the cross-platform power of modern HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript.

**2-Modularity**: With Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC `you can leverage the client and server pieces independently`, or together, depending on your preferences or project requirements. This cannot be done with Telerik Extensions.

kendo ui has what telerik has with 2 extras.kendo ui targets both desktop and mobile devices.this one is clear enough.but about the second one (Modularity) , you can feel this difference if you already have used KendoUI client side extensions before ASP.NET MVC.this means you can use telerik client extensions even if you are not an ASP.NET MVC developer (as a javascript developer) this is what you can not do with telerik extensions.

Comment: Means all that jquery related to KendoUI that's what you are talking about??

Comment: yes.i have been developing my applications with KendoUI (client side plugins) without Server side extensions for so many times (kendo ui first introduced for client programming not server side one).

Comment: You had used Telerik MVC extensions?? we have script in Telerik MVC extension also what about that?

Comment: yes telerik also take advantage of those script files.but they are not easy to use enough to be used with developers.

Comment: Is there any performance difference??

Comment: i don't think so.because they both use very similar code in server side and client side.